# Accessing Commerce product variant dimensions in the template

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, variants

I have been unable to locate anything in the docs or any questions on here regarding how to print the dimensions associated with a variant in the template.

All I have managed to find is how to print the dimension unit using the following:

```
{% set dimensionUnits = craft.commerce.settings.dimensionUnits %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimensions are set and accessed individually:

```
{% set variant = product.defaultVariant %}

{{ variant.width }}
{{ variant.height }}
{{ variant.length }}
{{ variant.weight }}
```